# Text in Konva Custom Shape

Tags: konvajs, konva

I need text output from my Custom Shape.

My code:
sceneFunc(context, shape) {

```
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.font = (15 / shape.parent.scale().x).toFixed(0) + "px arial";
    context.textBaseline = 'middle';
    context.textAlign = 'center';
    context.fillStyle = 'red';
  
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeText("AAABBBCCC", shape.attrs.centerPoint.x, shape.attrs.centerPoint.y);
    context.closePath();
    context.fillStrokeShape(shape);
}
```

The text is properly rendered, but it is not filled. How can I fill the text?

[Text output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eJ2I.png)

Answer (score 0):

`Konva` can't automatically fill/stroke text, because the text is using slightly different methods for drawings.

If you want to draw text in custom shape, you don't need to use `context.fillStrokeShape(shape);`. Just draw what you want in `sceneFunc`. Use `context.strokeText()` and `context.fillText()`.

Then manually create a hit graph (using rectangle) in `hitFunc`. For hit demo take a look here: https://konvajs.org/docs/events/Custom_Hit_Region.html#1-What-is-hitFunc